# Exception: Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed in serialize() (line 14

Tags: serialization, file-upload, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-9

I am using the latest update of Drupal 9. For some reason when I install any NEW module that involves uploading images, It goes through the motions of uploading but does not save image. The images don't show up on the content from the module. And when I go back to look at it, the image is blank like I never uploaded an image. So I checked my error logs.
Here is the error in the log:

Exception: Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed in serialize() (line 14 of /home/xxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxxx/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Serialization/PhpSerialize.php).

How do I fix this?

I tried asking drupal forums, No answer. I tried google. Nothing helped. I'm not that familiar with serialization.

Comment: First google search shows this: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3328986

Comment: tried that 

error: while searching for:
    if (isset($this->dataHash)) {
      return $this->dataHash;
    }
    $this->dataHash = Crypt::hmacBase64(serialize($this->getRawData()), Settings::getHashSalt());
    return $this->dataHash;
  }


error: patch failed: src/Entity/WebformSubmission.php:494
error: src/Entity/WebformSubmission.php: patch does not apply

Comment: Could you provide some more details, e.g. exakt Version? There is a core Bug in 9.5.x related to files: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2847425 maybe this has something to do with your Problem. Some guys said downgrade to 9.4.x fixed the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend clearing file field after entity gets persisted, but before getting redirected.

```
$entityManager = $this->registry->getManager();
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();

// To avoid serialization error
$user->setImageFile(null);

// flash message and/or redirect
```